# Python 2 string expression not recognised using Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a python script containing this regex:

```
expression1 = ur'(.*?),\s(.*)\s(sold(?: post-exercise)?|bought|purchased|awarded|exercised|transferred in|transferred out|re-invested)\s*([\d,]*).*price of\s*(\d*.\d+?p)'
```

Python parser barfs and complains its invalid Syntax.

Why is this invalid syntax in Python 3, yet valid in Python 2. 
Is there a way I can write it to work with both versions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2 `ur` strings had a weird incompatibility with Python 3, where `\u` and `\U` escapes would still be processed instead of being left "raw". When the `u` prefix was reintroduced to Python 3 in the 3.3 revision, an [explicit decision](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/#exclusion-of-raw-unicode-literals) was made to exclude the `ur` combination, rather than have inconsistent behavior.

If you want a raw Unicode string that works in both Python 2 and 3, you'll need a workaround. Possibilities include using a `br` raw bytestring and converting it to Unicode with an appropriate codec, or using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and using the plain `r` prefix. Be careful about `\u` and `\U` escapes.

Answer (score 2):

All strings in Python 3 are *unicode* so the leading `u` is not needed. Simply remove that `u` to make it work with Python 3.

Comment: No, a leading `u` on a string is perfectly fine in Python 3.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the best way to have Python 2/3 interoperability is to use:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Then simply remove the `u`. If you explicitely need bytes, then a `b"these are byte-strings"` will work for both 2/3.